# PHP GD - Crop Shape

Tags: php, gd, crop

I want to crop images using the GD, but I want it to crop around a particular shape rather than just a square.

Is this possible?

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to crop an image to a non-rectangular shape. Though you could in some manner use the shape as a mask and make the outside of that mask non-visible/alpha channel, maybe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it would be to create a mask in the desired square size, containing a alpha channel that is transparent.
And then laying it over the original image, that way you would be able to crop a circle.